# Given $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall\,x\in\mathbb{R}\,\,|f'(x)|\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Given $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall\,x\in\mathbb{R}\,\,|f'(x)|\leq 1$ ($f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$)

Then, $\forall\,x\neq y\,\,|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|$ (Neither a contraction nor a weak contraction)

But, does $f$ necessarily have a fixed point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x) = x - 1$, then $f'(x) = 1$, but no fixed points